# Lookup and multiply using fixed tables

Tags: datatables, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to set up a currency conversion using a fixed rate table.

This is an example of the currency rate table...

| Currency | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| CAD | .80 |
| EUR | 1.1 |

This is an example of the data table...

| Currency | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| CAD | 100000 |
| EUR | 100 |

My formula needs to convert to USD...
Currency Rate * Amount = USD

Ideally the finished table looks like this...

| Currency | Amount | USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAD | 100000 | 80000 |
| EUR | 100 | 110 |

What are the proper DAX formula(s) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculate measure to perform both Vlookup and calculation at the same time, here is the dax formula:

```
Forex Conversion = CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Amount]),Table2[Amount]) * 
                        CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Rate]),
                            FILTER(ALL(Table1),Table1[Currency] = EARLIER(Table2[Currency])))
```

The outcome:

[image]